# How to mount a FAT32 SD card as writeable?

Tags: usb, mount, sd-card, fat32

I have a FAT32 micro SD card which I want to write to. If I just stick it into my laptop's SD card slot and try to copy files in using the GUI, I get an error telling me the file system is read-only. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

So, I unmount with `umount`. Based on various different tutorials that I've read, I then try to remount using

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/joe/usb -o rw,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

It doesn't work; when I try `touch /media/joe/usb/test.txt` I get `touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Read-only file system`.

This is what happens with the lock switch on my micro SD to SD adapter in the unlocked position. In the locked position I get some different messages telling me the card is accessible for reading only. I tried the SD card in my android phone and I was able to write to it OK, and I've tried a different FAT32 card on my Ubuntu system which also work ok plug and play.

I don't know what the `umask` option means, but I saw some tutorials using it. I've tried with and without that option. I checked that 1000 is indeed the correct `uid` and `gid` for my user account in `/etc/passwd`

So what gives? How can I mount my card as writeable?

Comment: Some SD-cards have the capacity to be RO (*switch on the card itself*) until switch is physically changed; so check it. I'd also check the logs at time of mount for clues; as a RW gets *flipped* to RO if errors are detected, so as to protect data; and reason will be seen in logs (or `mount` command if read)

Comment: @guiverc It's a micro SD so it doesn't have a lock switch. I tried grepping for 'Mounted' in `/var/log/syslog*` and in `var/log/dmesg` and I can see `udisksd[882]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/joe/6EF5-E56B on behalf of uid 1000` logging my mount but no error messages or anything. Should I look somewhere else?

Comment: Just to check - further to guiverc's comment - are you using an adaptor to put into your laptop? if so, the adaptor probably has a lock switch even if the micro card doesn't.

Comment: @Will, yes I have checked all possible lock switches

Comment: I am familiar with USB sticks going into read-only mode. Usually it means they are defective. This could theoretically also happen to an SD card.. I know it's silly, but have you tried in another computer, preferably with another OS?  Just to make sure it's not the SD card.

Comment: @jawtheshark I tried it in my Android phone and I was able to write to it ok. It's only 1 year old. I also tried a different FAT32 card in Ubuntu, and I was able to write to that OK as well. Strange. Maybe I need to repair the filesystem on it?

Comment: I've seen flash based devices break after a few weeks. Age says nothing. Regardless, try an fsck on it (umount it, even when r/o) and then try fsck.  Or try Windows, it should complain when the filesystem is not in a good state... normally. I don't usually use Windows these days.

Comment: The commands would look something like this:
`sudo umount /dev/sdb1` to unmount.  Then `sudo fsck -fy /dev/sdb1` to check the filesystem.

Comment: @jawtheshark yep that did it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the file system was corrupted on my card. I `umount`ed, and then ran `sudo fsck -fy /dev/sdb1` as suggested by @jawtheshark, which fixed my problem and now I can write to the card.